# What's the purpose of <T> inside `function genericFunction<T>(arg:T): string {}`

Tags: generics, typescript

I'm reading about generic functions in TypeScript [here](https://narenaryan.gitbooks.io/typescript-for-the-impatient/content/generic_functions_of_typescript.html). The author provides an example of a generic function:

```
function genericFunction<T>(arg:T): string {
    return arg.toString();
}
```

I'm curios of the purpose of `<T>`. Without it, this

```
function genericFunction(arg:T): string {
    return arg.toString();
}
```

will gives an error `Error:(1, 30) TS2304:Cannot find name 'T'.`. So is it somehow telling compiler that the type `T` specified in the function should be treated as generic? So to define a simple function we need to use name, to define a generic function, we need to use `name<type here>` identifier?

At the bottom, the author shows another usage of `<T>`:

```
function xValue<T extends Point>
```

which is used to tell a compiler that the type `T` will have properties defined on the `Point` interface.

I understand what a generic function is. The question is about the purpose of `<T>` identifier in generic function syntax.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
function genericFunction<T>
```

This `<T>` here is the *introduction* of the generic type to this function. You're basically saying *we have a function here, and we are using a generic type in it, and it is T*.

Introducing the T there allows you to use it as a type in the rest of the function.

If you omit `<T>`, the function does not know you're using a generic type and it will not work.

Comment: thanks, so I can use any name for a new type? `function genericFunction<Boo>` seems to work too

Comment: Yes, although T is a widely accepted standard, like `int i`

Comment: Yeah that is correct. You are just naming the type. T is a standard but not enforced by compilers, that is all

Comment: so, can't we have a non-generic function with a generic parameter ?

Comment: @gkb no, that wouldn't make sense. A `function f<T>` can have a generic parameter *because* it is a generic function

Comment: @TimCastelijns, thanks, but the name of the function is missing there `<TFunction extends Function>(target: TFunction)`, why? I tried to add it there `fname<TFunction extends Function>(target: TFunction)` but I get an error: cannot find name `fname`.

Comment: yes but in that snippet you're not declaring a function, so the syntax is different. But the generics concept is the same

Comment: @TimCastelijns, ok, thanks, I'll try to understand the difference