# What's the difference between declaring a generic function and declaring a type for generic function

Tags: typescript

I have two examples of using generic function:

```
function genericFunction<TFunction extends Function>(target:TFunction): string {
    return target.toString();
}
```

According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40782923/2545680), this is generic function declaration.

Then this:

```
declare type ClassDecorator = <TFunction extends Function>(target: TFunction) => TFunction | void;
```

According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40715777/2545680), this a type declaration for a generic function.

I can't seem to understand when each is used. Can somebody please provide examples of usage for both?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first one is a generic function, it receives one argument which is of the type of the generic constraint.
It's a plain js function, and it will be part of the compiled js.

The second one is a [type alias](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#type-aliases) for a generic function type, for example the following functions match this type:

```
let fn1: ClassDecorator = function<T extends Function>(target: T): void {
    // ...
}

let fn2: ClassDecorator = function<T extends Function>(target: T): T {
    // ...
}
```

The type is only in typescript, it won't be present in the compiled js.

Comment: thanks, how do you know it's a `type alias` and not declaring a new type?

Comment: Because when you use the `type TYPE_NAME = ...` syntax then you are creating a type alias.

Comment: what's the syntax for declaring a new type?

Comment: A new type is basically to create an `interface`, a `class` and an `enum`. The `type` keyword means type alias.

Comment: In any meaningful sense, a type alias is also creating a new type, just like the other constructs.

Comment: thanks, can you please add more examples of using `type alias`, I'm having hard time understand it when it's used with functions :(

Comment: There can be way too many examples, it depends what exactly you want to know. Have you read the docs about the type aliases? Which part don't you get?

Comment: can I create a type alias for the function, that is not generic? if so how?

Comment: Sure thing: `type MyFunction = (x: number, y: number) => number;` is a type alias for a function which receives two numbers and return a number.

Comment: @NitzanTomer, thanks. so as I see the difference between a simple function type alias and generic function type alias is that the latter simply introduces new type here `<TFunction extends Function>` before the parenthesis, correct?

Comment: Yes, it's the same different as with a regular function and a regular function with generics. Though that this `TFunction` isn't a "new type", it's just a generic constraint.

Comment: thanks for your answers, it's getting clearer :). last question, why did you not use `declare` in your example `type MyFunction...`? what's the difference, in short, between using declare and not?

Comment: The `declare` keyword is used to tell the compiler that this variable/function/type/etc are defined somewhere else.  The compiler will then won't output it to the compiled js.  When declaring an interface/type alias the compiler won't add it to the generated definition files (in case the option is set in the compiler options).